# A geometry question

Tags: geometry

[image]

I think $B$ and $C$ aren't correct because maximum possible is $4$ but that too is possible iff $EFGH \equiv ABCD$
How to approach these kinds of questions?

So the answer is $C$

Comment: "*maximum possible is 4*" $\;-\;$ That actually excludes $A$ and $D$. Now find a minimum that excludes one of the two options left. Or, think at Pythagoras', and what the range is of $x^2 + (1-x)^2$ on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approaching this directly with $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ is tricky, because (typically) if you increase $\alpha$, you will decrease $\beta$, so it's hard to tell whether the sum increases or decreases.  However, let $a,b,c,d$ be the distances $AE,BF,CG,DH$.  Then by Pythagoras, the sum is
$$a^2+(1-a)^2$$
plus three similar terms.  Since $a,b,c,d$ do not affect each other, all you have to do is find the maximum and minimum of this expression (noting $0\le a\le1$) and then multiply by $4$.  I'll leave the details to you.

Comment: Thanks! I just did it the way you and @dxiv suggested